Does deploying auto-generated documentation to GitHub Pages require committing the website files to gh-pages branch?
I am generating documentation for my project for GitHub Pages, but I am doing it by running Jekyll/Doxygen and committing the results back to the repo.
This feels wrong; all these files are auto-generated, why am I tracking them in git? Do I have to track all these auto-generated files in my repo even though I have the source files in the repo and can rebuild them any time?
I cannot seem to figure out a GitHub workflow which builds my documentation with Jekyll/Doxygen then deploys it without committing back to the repo.
Is this necessary? Do I have to commit the output of Jekyll/Doxygen back to the repo in order to host it on GitHub Pages?
To further clarify my situation, I have a main branch master which is the core software - then I have several 'derivative' branches like branch1, branch2, branch3 which are derivatives of master but will never be merged back into master because they are for different purposes. Each of these branches has its own Doxygen documentation because their source code is slightly different.
I want to generate documentation for the entirety of the repo with Jekyll, I have the md files and such for that in a /docs folder in a gh-pages branch. But then, included in that Jekyll wiki, I also want to expose all of the Doxygen docs for each branch.
I want a workflow which can:

take the Jekyll md source files and generate the Jekyll wiki
check out each derivative branch and generate its Doxygen docs
store each derivative branch's Doxygen docs in a subfolder of the Jekyll wiki
deploy the Jekyll wiki and Doxygen docs to GitHub Pages

Do I need to commit Jekyll/Doxygen outputs back to my repo in order to host them on GitHub Pages? Or can I just "build and deploy" them in a single workflow?

Depends how you want to do it - if you publish from a branch then yes, but you could just deploy an artifact using https://github.com/actions/deploy-pages.

'deploying and artifact' sounds like exactly what I want, I attempted to achieve that but had issues and came to the conclusion maybe it wasn't possible. I will circle back and start looking over that approach again, up till now I just didn't know if that was even possible thank you

E.g. my repo https://github.com/textbook/abv has no gh-pages branch but does have a GitHub Pages site. Documented at https://docs.github.com/en/pages/getting-started-with-github-pages/configuring-a-publishing-source-for-your-github-pages-site

Thanks @jonrsharpe that's much more concise than what I was using before. Just updated my own site!

@jonrsharpe May I suggest you add an answer to this question with the Upload and Deploy steps from your site here? When I first tried to use deploy-pages, I was frustrated by how complicated it seemed to use deploy-pages, when you try to do it just from its own documentation. But your workflow cuts through it all with a good minimal complete usage, so it would be very useful here.

His workflow is good but it's missing a few steps for my solution, note the 4 steps in my question -- specifically the part about checking out other branches and generating doxygen and including the output of those in the artifacts to upload. Note, I will be using his workflow as a source of reference for part of it but I am still working to figure out the rest. When I get around to finishing this and have something working I'll be sure to post it back here as an answer too.
